# What are the available Sybase non interactive command line tools for Windows

Tags: sybase

I am searching for command line tools to execute the script files in Sybase. If anyone could point me to a download links will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sybase` is actually not a database, since there are 3 different database from the Sybase brand: Sybase ASE, Sybase IQ and Sybase SQL Anywhere (Incidentally, Sybase has been renamed to SAP since quite a few years.)
For ASE, the standard tool for batch execution is `isql -i`. For IQ or SQL Anywhere, you can use `dbisql -nogui`. See the respective documentation for details.